# Проверить инпут на MIME-type файлов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать проверку на файлы которые можно прикрепить для вставки в img?
Нужны только графические форматы

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
      var file = this.files;
      if (file[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file[0], 'UTF-8');
        reader.onload = function (event) {
          var result = event.target.result;
          $('.user-img').attr('src', event.target.result);
        };
      }
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="ec-photo-resource-3" name="photo" multiple accept="image/jpeg,image/png"/>
<img class="user-img" src="assets/img/svg/icon-author.svg" width="40" height="40">
<label for="ec-photo-resource-3"></label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Пища для размышления:**

```
$.each(this.files, function(i, file){
if(file['size']]>1024){
alert('Файл слишком большой');
return false;
}


var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e){

$('.combineLoaded').append('<div class="readUploadedFile ovh boxs posr"><div class="loadedImageName"><div class="fileName posr boxs ovh" title="'+ file['name'] +'">'+ file['name'] +'</div></div><img src="'+event.target.result+'" alt="'+ file['name'] +'" title="'+ file['name'] +'"></div>');
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```